# Using GROUP BY to only show the row with latest update for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I've been having trouble figuring out the syntax to do a `GROUP BY` to only show the row that has the latest `ups.db_LastUpdate` for each User (by `db_UserId`).

```
SELECT up.db_FirstName, up.db_LastName, up.db_UserId, ups.db_Initials, ups.db_LastUpdate 
FROM tblUserProfile up
    JOIN tblUserSel ups
        ON ups.db_Code = up.db_UserId
WHERE ups.db_UserTech = 'U'
```

Output (There will be several hundred users, but you get the point):

```
Jeff | Ledger | 1-34 | JL | 2015-08-11
Jeff | Ledger | 1-34 | DBC | 2015-06-06
Jeff | Ledger | 1-34 | YX | 2015-08-01
John | Barker | 1-26 | JR | 2015-04-04
John | Barker | 1-26 | YY | 2015-02-18
John | Barker | 1-26 | FF | 2015-11-14
```

Maybe something like `GROUP BY ups.dbUserId, MAX(db_LastUpdate)`

Thanks for your help

Comment: GROUP BY whateverColumns,...  HAVING MAX(db_LastUpdate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  up.db_FirstName, 
            up.db_LastName, 
            up.db_UserId, 
            ups.db_Initials, 
            ups.db_LastUpdate,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY up.db_UserId ORDER BY ups.db_LastUpdate DESC)
    FROM tblUserProfile up
    INNER JOIN tblUserSel ups
            ON ups.db_Code = up.db_UserId
    WHERE ups.db_UserTech = 'U'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

As pointed in the comments, you can use `MAX` and then join with your table:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  up.db_UserId, 
            MAX(ups.db_LastUpdate) MaxLastUpdate
    FROM tblUserProfile up
    INNER JOIN tblUserSel ups
            ON ups.db_Code = up.db_UserId
    WHERE ups.db_UserTech = 'U'
    GROUP BY up.db_UserId
)
SELECT B.*
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN tblUserSel B
    ON A.db_UserId = B.db_Code
    AND A.MaxLastUpdate = B.db_LastUpdate;
```

But you need to know that if there exists a row with the same date for the same user you'll get those 2 rows as a result.

Comment: Do you think it would be helpful to add a `MAX()` solution as well to show other options?

Comment: @Zane well, alright, I added that option to the answer

Comment: You and your CTE's :)

Comment: @Zane yup, I like them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have a unique ID column, I usually handle that situation something like this:

```
WITH LastEdit AS (
    SELECT ups.db_Code, ups.db_Initials, ups.db_LastUpdate
    FROM tblUserSel ups
    WHERE ups.db_UserTech = 'U' AND ups.ID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 ID
        FROM tblUserSel upsn
        WHERE ups.db_Initials = upsn.db_Initials
        ORDER BY upsn.db_LastUpdate DESC
    )
)
SELECT up.db_FirstName, up.db_LastName, up.db_UserId, le.db_Initials, le.db_LastUpdate 
FROM tblUserProfile up
    INNER JOIN LastEdit le
        ON le.db_Code = up.db_UserId
```